# How to add multiple horizontal ribbons (like geom_hlines) in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot some horizontal lines onto a scatterplot (e.g. with geom_hline) and then put some error ribbons around those lines that have different widths for each line.

I have a data frame consisting of a continuous x and y and grouping factor:

```
#make the dataframe:
so<-data.frame(expand.grid(x=c(1:5),sys=c("a","b","c","d")))
so$y<-c(1,2,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,4,3,4,5)
```

And a second dataframe with information for some hlines and error ribbons that I would like to add to the plot:

```
#make the second dataframe:
so2<-data.frame(sys=c("a","b","c","d"),yint=c(1.4,2.3,3.5,4.6),low=c(1.2,2.1,3.4,4.1),
            upp=c(1.6,2.7,3.6,4.7))
```

I can create a plot with the hlines:

```
ggplot(so,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=sys)) + 
 geom_point(position=position_jitter()) +
 geom_hline(data=so2,aes(yintercept=yint,colour=sys))
```

[image]

But if I try to put the ribbons around them, the ggplot gets lost without x values:

```
ggplot(so,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=sys)) + 
 geom_point(position=position_jitter()) +
 geom_hline(data=so2,aes(yintercept=yint,colour=sys))+
 geom_ribbon(data=so2,aes(ymin=low,ymax=upp))
   #Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found
```

Is it possible to get geom_ribbon to act like geom_hline? Or is there a workaround of e.g. plotting the upper and lower bounds as hlines and somehow shading between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but if you use geom_rect() instead of geom_ribbon() you can indicate the upper/lower bounds, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
so<-data.frame(expand.grid(x=c(1:5),sys=c("a","b","c","d")))
so$y<-c(1,2,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,4,3,4,5)
#make the second dataframe:
so2<-data.frame(sys=c("a","b","c","d"),yint=c(1.4,2.3,3.5,4.6),low=c(1.2,2.1,3.4,4.1),
                upp=c(1.6,2.7,3.6,4.7))  

ggplot(so,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=sys)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_jitter()) +
  geom_hline(data=so2,aes(yintercept=yint, colour=sys)) +
  geom_rect(data = so2, aes(ymin = low, ymax = upp,
                            xmin = 0.5, xmax = 5.5, fill=sys),
            alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image: example_2.png]

The issue with geom_ribbon() is that you have a single upper / lower bounds for all values of x, so I don't know how to make it work with geom_ribbon() unless your actual data is different to this minimal reproducible example. Hopefully this helps and makes sense.

Comment: Thanks - that is exactly what I was trying to achieve! (had tried geom_rect() but must have missed something as it didn't work, so thanks very much for the example code)